# Concatenating and sorting a list of list array

Tags: python, sorting

I have a CSV file containing list of postcodes of different persons which involves travelling from one postcode to another for different jobs, a person could travel to 5 postcoodes a day. using numpy array, I got list of list of postcodes.  I then concatenate the list of postcode to get one big list of postcode using `a = np.concatenate(b)`, after which I want to sort it in an alphabetical order, I used : `print(np.sort(a))` is gave me error **error AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0**

I also tried using `a.sort()` but it is giving me **`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'`**

Please, can someone help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: cols = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
df = pd.read_csv('my_work.csv')
df1 = df.iloc[:, cols]
a= np.array(df1)
print(a)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing in both floats and strings into your list.
Try converting the values in b into a float before you concatenate them.